# How to search max value from group in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, greatest-n-per-group

I am just learning some SQL, so I have a question.

-I have a table with name `TABL`

-a variable `:ccname` which has a value "`Bottle`"

The table is as follows:

```
   +----------+---------+-------+--------+
   | Name     |  Price  |  QTY  |  CODE  |
   +----------+---------+-------+--------+ 
   | Rope     |   3.6   |   35  |   236  |
   | Chain    |   2.8   |   15  |   237  |
   | Paper    |   1.6   |   45  |   124  |
   | Bottle   |   4.5   |   41  |   478  |
   | Bottle   |   1.8   |   12  |   123  | 
   | Computer | 1450.75 |   71  |   784  |
   | Spoon    |   0.7   |   10  |   412  |
   | Bottle   |   1.3   |   15  |   781  |
   | Rope     |   0.9   |   14  |   965  |
   +----------+---------+-------+--------+
```

Now I want to find the `CODE` from the variable `:ccname` with the higher quantity! So I translated like this:

```
SELECT CODE
FROM TABL
GROUP BY :ccname
WHERE QTY=MAX(QTY)
```

In a perfect world that would turn as a result `478`.
In the SQL world what should I write in order to get `478`?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Ok I did it. It is microsoft sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT CODE
FROM TABLENAme
WHERE QTY = (SELECT MAX(QTY) FROM TablName WHERE Name = :ccname)
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like that:

```
SELECT code 
FROM TABL
WHERE Name=:ccname
ORDER BY QTY DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The idea is we find all rows of the table whose `Name` column is the same as the contents of the variable `:ccname`, then order them by the quantity in descending order, and filally we select first one, which has to be the one with the largest quantity because they are sorted in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY`, a proper `WHERE`, and the something to limit the result set to one row:

```
SELECT CODE
FROM TABL
WHERE name = :ccname
ORDER BY QTY DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Note:  Some databases spell the ANSI standard `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` as `LIMIT` or as `SELECT TOP 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific database, you can use one of the following options to restrict your result set to a single value after ordering your existing columns through an `ORDER BY` clause:

- `SELECT TOP 1`
- `LIMIT 1`
- `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY`

**Syntax Examples**

```
  SELECT TOP 1 Code
    FROM TABL
   WHERE Name = :ccname
ORDER BY QTY DESC
```

or

```
  SELECT Code
    FROM TABL
   WHERE Name = :ccname
ORDER BY QTY DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

or

```
  SELECT CODE
    FROM TABL
   WHERE Name = :ccname
ORDER BY QTY DESC
   FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using join can also effectively solve the question:

```
Select t1.Code
From   TABL As t1 Join (
      Select Name, Max(table.QTY) as MaxQTY
      From   TABL
      Where  Name = :ccname
      Group by Name
) As t2
Where t1.QTY = t2.MaxQTY And t1.Name = t2.Name
```

Explanation:

You first calculate the maximum value for "Bottle" using the subquery and then join the two tables to select corresponding row with MaxQTY and same name.